# Client testing - simulate construct_runtime! and to include specific pallet into test runtime

Tags: pallet, client

I have client which works in parallel with custom pallet through Api implementation. To do proper testing I have to implement pallet for runtime similarly how `construct_runtime!` does to be able to refer to it. What is the approach to achieve this? Maybe some client already implements this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `construct_runtime!`?

In every pallet, we write tests which mock a runtime environment like this:

```rust
use crate as pallet_template;
use frame_support::traits::{ConstU16, ConstU64};
use frame_system as system;
use sp_core::H256;
use sp_runtime::{
    testing::Header,
    traits::{BlakeTwo256, IdentityLookup},
};

type UncheckedExtrinsic = frame_system::mocking::MockUncheckedExtrinsic<Test>;
type Block = frame_system::mocking::MockBlock<Test>;

// Configure a mock runtime to test the pallet.
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Config, Storage, Event<T>},
        TemplateModule: pallet_template::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
    }
);

impl system::Config for Test {
    type BaseCallFilter = frame_support::traits::Everything;
    type BlockWeights = ();
    type BlockLength = ();
    type DbWeight = ();
    type Origin = Origin;
    type Call = Call;
    type Index = u64;
    type BlockNumber = u64;
    type Hash = H256;
    type Hashing = BlakeTwo256;
    type AccountId = u64;
    type Lookup = IdentityLookup<Self::AccountId>;
    type Header = Header;
    type Event = Event;
    type BlockHashCount = ConstU64<250>;
    type Version = ();
    type PalletInfo = PalletInfo;
    type AccountData = ();
    type OnNewAccount = ();
    type OnKilledAccount = ();
    type SystemWeightInfo = ();
    type SS58Prefix = ConstU16<42>;
    type OnSetCode = ();
    type MaxConsumers = frame_support::traits::ConstU32<16>;
}

impl pallet_template::Config for Test {
    type Event = Event;
}

// Build genesis storage according to the mock runtime.
pub fn new_test_ext() -> sp_io::TestExternalities {
    system::GenesisConfig::default().build_storage::<Test>().unwrap().into()
}
```

and then tests like:

```rust
use crate::{mock::*, Error};
use frame_support::{assert_noop, assert_ok};

#[test]
fn it_works_for_default_value() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        // Dispatch a signed extrinsic.
        assert_ok!(TemplateModule::do_something(Origin::signed(1), 42));
        // Read pallet storage and assert an expected result.
        assert_eq!(TemplateModule::something(), Some(42));
    });
}

#[test]
fn correct_error_for_none_value() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        // Ensure the expected error is thrown when no value is present.
        assert_noop!(TemplateModule::cause_error(Origin::signed(1)), Error::<Test>::NoneValue);
    });
}
```

These are from the `node-template`, but should be doable in whatever context you want.